# Two UIButtons calling the same method have different results

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, datetime, uibutton

I have a UIButton that displays a time, and this time is displayed in the titleLabel property of the UIButton. To change this time, you can click on the button, which calls this method that brings in a date picker.

```
- (IBAction)slidePickerIn:(id)sender {
    // Ok button to dismiss picker
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.datePickerOK];
    // Bring picker to front
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.datePicker];
    // animate entrance of picker and fade in of dismiss button
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [self.datePicker setFrame:pickerIn];
        self.datePickerOK.alpha = 1;
    }];
}
```

When you click on the dismiss button, this method gets called. It gets rid of the date picker and the dismiss button and it updates the title of the button displaying the time.

```
- (IBAction)slideDatePickerOut {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        self.datePickerOK.alpha = 0;
        [self.datePicker setFrame:pickerOut];
    }];

    // Set time correctly
    NSDate *wake = self.datePicker.date;
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    self.wakeUpTime.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [df stringFromDate:wake]];
    self.wakeUpTime.date = wake;
}
```

There is another button on the screen that also calls slidePickerIn and allows you to change the time.

THE PROBLEM: When I click on this other button to change the date displayed, everything works fine. However, when I click on the button itself, that contains the title showing the time, the date goes to 00:00 AM (the default value) while the date picker is displayed. When the date picker is dismissed, the time updates correctly. But as I said, using the other button doesn't change the value of the time while the picker is displayed. I am really unsure of why this could be. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Minor detail--creating and formatting a date formatter takes almost half a second.  You should make it static and only do it once.

Comment: This is a perfect time to set a breakpoint. Add a symbolic breakpoint in -[UILabel setText:], and enable it just before you tap the button that is giving you the problem. Something is sending a setText: message with the wrong value. When the code breaks in the debugger, you will be able to trace the code causing the change.

Comment: @HalR you mean I should keep the formatter in a property so I don't have to create it every time?

Comment: @BoredAstronaut thanks, that was very helpful. Indeed, when I click on the button, setText is called, but on the debugger I only see the crazy code from the objc classes and as I step out of them, I never reach any code of my own. So basically no idea what's calling this setText

Comment: Yes, keep the formatter around.  Doing so as a property would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your slidePickerIn add:

```
if(self.datePicker.alpha == 0)
{
    //Add all the methods
}
```

In your slidePickerOut add:

```
if(self.datePicker.alpha == 1)
{
    //Add all the methods
}
```

Now the UIButtons will be called in the correct time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not assigned both methods to button